# How to parse through JSON file using javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to parse through the following JSON file using Javascript. Can somebody help me with how to retrieve the data from this kind of JSON structure?

```
{
    "game_schedule": [
            {
                "day1":{
                    "date": "05/21/2016",
                    "time": ["09:06 am", "12:00 pm", "08:05 pm"],
                    "game": [
                        "SF Giants vs NY Mets",
                        "LA Dodgers vs SD Padres",
                        "SF Giants vs SD Padres"
                        ]
                },
                "day2":{
                    "date": "05/22/2016",
                    "time": ["09:06 am", "04:09 pm"],
                    "game": [
                        "LA Dodgers vs SF Gaints",
                        "LA Dodgers vs NY Mets"
                        ]

            }
        }
    ]  
}
```

Comment: json is javascript. Did you did the json from server? In that case what have gotten is probably a string? Show your parsing code.

Comment: When a JSON file is parsed (with `JSON.parse`), it becomes a JavaScript dictionary and can be accessed in the normal ways.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking? What have you tried?

Comment: @SureshKoya - JSON is *not* Javascript. JSON is a string representation of data that happens to look a lot like JavaScript code.

Comment: @nnnnn - json is [Javascript Object Notation](http://www.json.org/)

Comment: @SureshKoya - And as the page you linked to says, JSON "is a text format that is completely language independent". Yes, the "JS" stands for "JavaScript", but that's because the format was *inspired* by JavaScript's object and array literal syntax, not because it *is* JavaScript.

Comment: I tried to do something similar as mentioned on this page : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/
Basically my idea is that information will be sent by server to client in JSON file and browser will read JSON file to retrieve that info. So I tried to do something as mentioned on the link I shared but not able to make it work for my structure for some reason. Sorry if my question is dumb, I'm a noob in web development. Let me know if I can clarify any further.

Comment: To access object properties, you can use dot notation or bracket notation. To access array elements, you can use bracket notation.

Comment: Technically JSON is string/text and since JavaScript works with string/text, maybe it could be considered a very very very limited subset of JavaScript.  But by that perspective, it would also be a subset of any language (compiled or scripting) that deals with strings such as C, Java, Py, Swift, Ruby, etc.  Therefore, we can say that because all these high level languages can claim it, that it should be considered language agnostic much like other structured text languages (e.g., CSV, TXT).  But because JSON has it's own syntax and structure we could consider it a markup language of its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var obj = JSON.parse( json_string );

// obj['game_schedule'][0]['day1']['date'] == '05/21/2016'
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you please tell how to do it if JSON string is in a file?

Comment: You'd need to specify how the file is stored. Where it's located. How it's accessed etc. Try googling that bit first. It might be a separate question for you.